# Introduction to Geometry Books

Tags: geometry, reference-request

I am looking for a book that covers introduction to geometry. Currently, I am reading "*Geometry: A metric approach with models*", by R.S Millman. I like the book but I would like to read another highly recommended book(s) to go along with it.

Are there any other highly recommend book which will be good for an introduction to geometry that will ideally have a solution manual?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It really depends on what kind of Geometry you want to get started in. Here my suggestions

> **General Geometry**

- [Geometry for Dummies](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470089466) - *very basic*
- [The Elements](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Byrne-Books-Euclid-Bibliotheca-Universalis/dp/3836559382/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_14_t_2?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=9WX1K1ZX3APBNXC7TDP0) - Euclid
- [Geometry Unbound](https://kskedlaya.org/geometryunbound/gu-060118.pdf) - Kedlaya - *very good (and free)*
- [Essential Geometry: A Self-Teaching Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1937842398) - Tim Hill
- [Plane and Solid Geometry](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387782409) - Aarts

> **Olympiad Geometry**

- [Euclidean Geometry in Mathematical Olympiads](http://web.evanchen.cc/geombook.html) - Evan Chen - *Excellent*
- [Introduction to Geometry](https://artofproblemsolving.com/store/item/intro-geometry) - Richard Rusczyk
- [Problem-Solving and Selected Topics in Euclidean Geometry](https://www.isinj.com/mt-usamo/Problem-Solving%20and%20Selected%20Topics%20in%20Euclidean%20Geometry%20In%20the%20Spirit%20of%20the%20Mathematical%20Olympiads%20-%20Louridas,%20Rassias%20(2013).pdf) - Louridas

*Note*: From now on, the books might not necessarily be *introduction*-books. This rather depends on your knowledge...

> **Analytic Geometry**

- [An Introduction to Analytic Geometry and Calculus](https://www.sciencedirect.com/book/9780121422523/an-introduction-to-analytic-geometry-and-calculus) - A.C. Burdette

> **Non-euclidean Geometry**

- [Introduction to Non-Euclidean Geometry](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486498506) - Harold E. Wolfe

> **Algebraic Geometry**

- [Geometry of algebraic curves](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540426882) - Arbarello

> **Differential Geometry**

- [An Introduction to Differentiable Geometry](http://An%20Introduction%20to%20Differential%20Geometry%20(Dover%20Books%20on%20Mathematics)) - T. J. Willmore
- [Differential geometry: manifolds, curves, and surfaces](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387966267) - Berger
- [Curves and surfaces](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9788847019409) - Abate

> **Discrete Geometry**

- [Lectures on Discrete Geometry](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387953731) - Matousek

> **4d-Geometry**

- [Beyond the Third Dimension](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0716760150) - Thomas F. Banchoff
- If you prefer videos, [here](http://www.dimensions-math.org) you can find awesome explanations for the different dimensions

---

***Addendum***

I've just remembered, that there's a really nice book on geometry I would like to recommend you: Episodes in nineteenth and twentieth century Euclidean Geometry (from Ross Honsberger).

This book might not offer an introduction to geometry - however, it presents very interesting geometry properties (especially in triangles - the most studied geometry polygon) that can be proven with clever manipulations of elementary geometry.

Comment: Thanks! Can you also recommend which book to read first, for example, I should first read one of the "general geometry" before jumping into non-Euclidean geometry book?

Comment: Well, if I were you, I would start with Geometry Unbound... If your approach is rather olympic, I would definitively start with Introduction to Geometry from Richard Rusczyk and then jump to Evan Chen...

Comment: Now, beyond the introduction/basics, deciding whether to continue with non-euclidean, analytic, ..., 4d Geometry really depends on what you like more. I, for instance, prefer 2d euclidean Geometry, since I find it very difficult to imagine 3d *Volumina* and even more difficult to work with 4d; this is the reason why I then jumped to Analytic Geometry... However, I have a friend that enjoyed a lot figuring out how to work with objects in 4d, so... it's really up to you

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a very detailed treatment of Euclidean geometry with rigorous proofs from axioms, I'd recommend John Lee's [Axiomatic Geometry](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0821884786).  No solution manual, although many theorems proved in detail in the text serve as good examples for the exercises.

Comment: Thank you! I am suprised there aren't any other answers to this question. I guess geometry isn't popular here lol. I got a lot of answers for my real analysis book recommendation but only one answer for geometry lol.

Comment: I'm reading John Lee's Axiomatic Geometry and I like it. Can you recommend books about axiomatic solid geometry and analytic geometry that are rigorous like John Lee's book?

Comment: Glad to hear you liked it.  But sorry, I don't know of similar books for solid geometry or analytic geometry off-hand.  (Which is not to say they don't exist.)

Answer (score 2):

I personally enjoyed "Elementary Geometry from an Advanced Standpoint," by Edwin Moise. It has some nice historical remarks on how early ideas about ratios were essentially closely related to Dedekind cuts, etc. And Coxeter's books are pretty widely admired, although I've only dipped into them here and there.